# List CSV cells with same value in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, excel

I've got a CSV with agency names and addresses. If I want a string of agency names with the same address (specifically the same zip code), how can I do that in R or Python? Whichever way is most efficient is preferable, but I'm still learning both. Google Refine gave me the counts of each zip code cluster already, but I just need to know which agencies correspond to those zips.

PS. Yes I know zip code isn't good to rely upon; the point of this is to illustrate that.

Example input data:

[image]

Final output (to be merged with shapefiles later):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just construct a dictionary:

```
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

agencies = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.csv', 'r') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)

    for row in reader:
        agencies[row[2]].append(row[0])
```

Now, `agencies` contains a mapping of zip codes to agencies.

Comment: @grich: That's a problem with `csv`. I've never seen it before, so here's a [ton of Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error:+new-line+character+seen+in+unquoted+field+-+do+you+need+to+open+the+file+in+universal-newline+mode&num=100&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=u&tbm=dsc&sa=X&ei=JTzGULSADcKCyAGi2IHgAw&ved=0CEUQmAcwAQ&biw=1440&bih=799) for that exact problem.

Comment: what about writing the list to a single cell? writerows just wants to separate each item in the list into separate cells.

Comment: @grich: You can do `for zipcode in agencies: writer.writerow(zipcode, *agencies[zipcode])`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough sketch of an R solution using simulated data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(agency = sample(letters[1:15],100,replace = TRUE),
                  zipcode = sample(15,100,replace = TRUE))

head(dat)

#A base R solution
aggregate(dat$agency,
          by = list(dat$zipcode),
          FUN = function(x){paste(x,collapse = ",")})

#Or using the populat plyr package
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,
      .(zipcode),
      summarise,
      agencies = paste(agency,collapse = ","))
```

Screen shots of your data are not generally the most useful thing to show. A complete, minimal reproducible example would allow for more complete answers that are more directly helpful. (And lead to fewer follow-up questions on your part.)

Comment: @grich joran's comment about a minimal reproducible example is very important. It dramatically increases the chance that complete answers that solve the actual problem can be given.